# asp.net web application control client's screen

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have this project requirement, An online exam where there are examinees and one examiner. Each examinee has own computer to where they will be answering the exam. However examinee has no control to move to next question only examiner has this control. Once the examiner move to next question all examinee's screen will move to next question also. Is it possible in asp.net web application? Any idea please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Adopting signalR should allows this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr